# How can I silently install Azure Az Powershell modules from the MSI file?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-rm

The MSI file can be seen here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v1.4.0-February2019

How can I install this file quietly through a script? (I am doing this inside a Docker container). The older AzureRM commandlets install fine (from the same GitHub repo, version 6.13.1 for example), but this one fails without any error.

I've tried installing with

```
msiexec.exe /i "D:\Azure-Cmdlets-6.13.1.24243-x64.msi" /qn
```

which works. But for Az,

```
msiexec.exe /i "D:\Az-Cmdlets-1.4.0.26146-x64.msi" /qn
```

doesn't work!

I'm installing it into a vanilla container without AzureRM present, so there shouldn't be any conflict.

Comment: Try `Start-Process "D:\Az-Cmdlets-1.4.0.26146-x64.msi" /qn -Wait`

Comment: Same thing :( Just drops straight back to powershell, without any errors

Comment: @Timtam Any reason to install via the MSI and not install it from the gallery?

Comment: @Persistent13 Cannot rely on an untrusted source for the installation (i.e. public internet) for compliance reasons.

Comment: @Timtam An alternative option is to save the raw nuget file from the gallery, validate it per your guidelines, and then setup an internal nuget or file based repository. Aside from that have you attempted to have the installer write a log file and then view that?

Comment: @Persistent13 i did yes, but the raw nuget file does not install dependencies. The MSI includes all the dependencies. I tried doing the log file, but it does not show any errors.

Comment: I just posted a bounty, and I wished I wrote that I'm hoping for some powershell 5.1 to do the install, but I'll likely be able to make your cmd work if you're some sort of cmd savant.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this within a docker container yet, but the following command seems to be working on some VMs in my environment:

```
msiexec /i C:\temp\Az-Cmdlets-5.2.0.33762-x64.msi /QN /L*V "C:\temp\az.log" STARTAPP=1
```

I am doing some more tests to see if this will work on other machines.  I will update my answer here if that `STARTAPP=1` poses a problem and I need to find a better answer than this one.

I'm not sure why `STARAPP=1` seems to work.  I think it may have something to do with the way the package imports the other packages and it forces that to happen which then makes it work.